# Checked checkbox error

Tags: php, checkbox

What is wrong in this code ? I've tried it on google chrome and the checkbox was UNCKECKED but when trying it on firefox it was checked , how does the code of a CHECKED BOX really have to look like ?

```
2010-2013 <input type='checkbox' name='actual' value='YES' checked  ><br />
2000-2009 <input type='checkbox' name='09' value='YES' > <br />
1990-1999 <input type='checkbox' name='99' value='YES' > <br />
1980-1989 <input type='checkbox' name='89' value='YES' > <br />
1970-1979 <input type='checkbox' name='79' value='YES' > <br />
... -1969 <input type='checkbox' name='69' value='YES' > <br />
```

Comment: Looks checked to me in Chrome.

Comment: It works:http://jsfiddle.net/GeCe3/

Comment: Proof or it didn't happen

Comment: i too am using chrome. Unless I'm failing to grasp the concept of checked and unchecked?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type='checkbox' name='actual' value='YES' checked="checked"  >
```

Try This.

Comment: That works, but it shouldn't really make a difference **[proof](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/RB5x8/)**

Comment: @brbcoding The difference is, whether you use the XHTML (`checked="checked"`) or HTML (`checked`) notation. This should match your document type.